# Open Instagram with HTTP URL - opens first IG, and then Safari

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api, ios13

I'm testing on iOS 13.2 this link from a webpage:

```html
<a href="http://instagram.com/_u/test">Open IG</a>
```

It first opens the IG app, and then right away opens IG in Safari, and below displays a message if I want to switch to the app.

why does it make two actions at once?

I want to make only one action - either have it open Instagram right away with the correct path, or open instagram in web version right away.

I know I can use this link format instead:

```html
<a href="instagram://user?username=test">Open IG 2</a>
```

But it is not the format I wish to use, but I'm not sure if it supported on all phones, and also it might do nothing if a user does not have the app installed, right?